# PHP, header(redirect) not working on live server

Tags: php, redirect, header, localhost

I have this code

```
if(isset($_GET['elimina_id'])){
    if (in_array($_GET['elimina_id'], $_SESSION['cart']) ) {
        $index = (array_keys($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['elimina_id']));
        $i = $index[0];
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);
        header('location: cart.php');
    }
 }
```

Basically, I want to delete a item in the cart. The thing is, on the test page, localhost, everything works, but on live server I have problems with `header()`. If I put `header()` the item won't be deleted, the page only reloads without any action taken effect. If I don't put the `header()`, after I click the 'Delete item' link, nothing happens, but then if I manually reload the page it works, the item deletes.
On localhost I don't have this problem, what could it be? The php version is OK, could it be some settings in the .ini file ?
Hope you can help me, Thanks

Comment: put `ob_start();` in the first line of your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a meta redirect tag, or a javascript solution?

**HTML:**
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.site.com/cart.php">`

**JavaScript #1:**
`<script>window.location = "http://www.site.com/cart.php";</script>`

**JavaScript #2:** `<script>window.navigate("http://www.site.com/cart.php");</script>`

Comment: Thank you, this worked (only the HTML method), the only glitch is that during the redirect the table resizes, it becomes twice width/height. What I still don't understand is why header() doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) before `header('location: cart.php');`

Answer (score 2):

> **Solution:   Update the PHP version**

I had the same issue with my hosting,

- Header redirect not working
- Issue with SESSION
- etc

I got it solved by the hosting provider by updating the version of PHP

He just changed the php version from php 5.4 to 5.6 and it might have fixed the issue

So Ask your Hosting Provider to Update the PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

put `ob_start()` in the first line of your code,

```
ob_start();
if(isset($_GET['elimina_id'])){
if (in_array($_GET['elimina_id'], $_SESSION['cart']) ) {
    $index = (array_keys($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['elimina_id']));
    $i = $index[0];
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);
            header('location: cart.php');
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, ob_start() worked indeed, but now all items in the cart are deleted if I click 'Delete item', instead of just the one I clicked

Answer (score 1):

do like this

`<?php`

`ob_start();`

`if(isset($_GET['elimina_id'])){`

`if (in_array($_GET['elimina_id'], $_SESSION['cart']) ) {`

`$index = (array_keys($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['elimina_id']));`

`$i = $index[0];`

`unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);`

`header('location: cart.php');`

`}`

`}`

`ob_end_flush();`

`?>`
`

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
//-->
</script>
```